# juju debug-hooks not working

Tags: juju

I think `juju debug-hooks` is not working correctly. I'm not sure what the output should be, but I get nothing. When I <kbd>ctrl-c</kbd> the process, I het an error 130. What could be wrong?

```
juju debug-hooks nimbus/0
^CConnection to x.x.x.x closed.
ERROR subprocess encountered error code 130
```

Comment: Shortly after running that command you should be moved into a tmux terminal on the machine in question. Does this not happen? Are you able to `juju ssh nimbus/0` ?

Comment: Yes,  I'm able to do juju SSH. No, even after 10 minutes, no tmux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. Apparently tmux has to be installed on the node.

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

Comment: Glad you got it solved. This seems like a bug to me though because I've never had to manually install tmux to use debug-hooks before. A bug report with some additional information on your environment, Juju version, OS etc would be really helpful https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju-core/+bug/1429790/